# React testing query for material-ui radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I am trying to get radio mui radio button for testing but it fails. I used getByTestId, getByLabelText, queryByLabelText.

describe("Radio group test cases", ()=>{
test("Radio group change value and new value updated and last value no more checked", () => {
render();

```
    // Before change selection
    const radionButtonMale = screen.getByTestId('Male') as HTMLInputElement;
    //expect(radionButtonMale).toHaveProperty("checked", true);
    expect(radionButtonMale.checked).toEqual(true);

    // Change selection
    const radionButtonFemale = screen.getByTestId('Female') as HTMLInputElement;
    fireEvent.click(radionButtonFemale, { target: { checked: true }});
    expect(radionButtonFemale.checked).toEqual(true);

    // Old value is no more checked
    expect(radionButtonMale.checked).toEqual(false);
});
```

})

Index.ts

```
<>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <FormLabel id="buttons-group-label">{placeholder}</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup
        
        aria-labelledby="buttons-group-label"
          value={!value ? defaultValue : value}
         // onChange={onChange}
         
          // label={placeholder}
          name="radio-buttons-group"
          {...otherprops}
        >
          {fieldConfig?.options?.map((option) => (
            <FormControlLabel key={option.displayValue} value={option.displayValue} control={<Radio inputProps={{
              // @ts-ignore
              'data-testid': `${option.displayValue}`,
            }} />} label={option.displayValue} />
                        ))}
          
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
      {!valid && touched && <ErrorMessage>{errorMessage}</ErrorMessage>}
    </>
```

It Looks like material creating the nested radio button dom so I am unable to get the radio button.

Error:
[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text and provide the text as well.